# R plotly histogram uncorrect observations count

Tags: r, histogram, plotly

I'm having some trouble with an histogram plot with plotly.
It seems that the bins are wrong populated. Why?

```
aaa<-seq(-0.1,0.45,0.005)
plot_ly(y=~aaa,
        type="histogram",
        showlegend=FALSE,
        autobiny=FALSE,
        ybins=list(
              start=-0.1,
              end=0.45,
              size=0.005
              ),
        marker=list(
              line=list(
                  width=1
                  )
               )
)
```

The code create this wrong plot[image]

Comment: I think it a rounding issue. If you use `start=-0.1-0.005/2,` then all wokrs as expected, because every number lies in the binwidth.

Comment: Alternatively it might be due to binning rules (includes only first left, subsequently includes less than or equal to right break/bin). Change `aaa<-seq(-0.1005,0.45,0.005)` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could try building your histogram in `ggplot2` and use the `ggplotly` function like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
ggplotly(ggplot(data.frame(aaa), aes(aaa)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.005))
```